# How to save specific character into variable by shell script

Tags: bash, shell, powershell

I have a simple text which i want to filter it and then select second part of each line then save them into separate variable, i am new in shell scripting.
i am using GitBash on windows
thanks

**text.txt**

```
mytext `one or a`
mytext `two or b or bb`
mytext `three or c`
```

**script**

list=`grep "mytext" text.txt`

this is the output

```
echo "$list"
    mytext `one or a`
    mytext `two or b or bb
    mytext `three or c`
```

so i want to save the second part of each line into separate variable,
 for example:

```
echo $var01
`one or a`

echo $var02
`two or b or bb`
```

Comment: Can we assume you're using [tag:bash] and therefore remove the [tag:powershell] and [tag:sh] from your tags?

Comment: Why do you have the question tagged with so many tags ? `powershell` and `bash` are not the same thing at all. Please edit your question and simply keep the relevant tag

Comment: What environment are you using? Windows? Linux? MacOS? What shell are you using? Bourne? bash? Windows CMD? Windows PowerShell? PowerShell core (pwsh)? Please update your question, and remove any inappropriate tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a shell loop will do the job:

```
words=()
while read -r first rest; do
    [ "$first" = mytext ] || continue
    words+=( "$rest" )
done < file
```

This leaves you with the following (using `printf` to print on separate lines):

```
$ printf '%s\n' "${words[@]}"
`one or a`
`two or b or bb`
`three or c`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can user `awk` to extract the second parts from your input file, and then store them in a bash array:

```
#!/bin/bash

# declare array "WORDS"
declare -a WORDS
INDEX=0
for WORD in $(awk '/mytext/ { print $2 }' text.txt) ; do
    # insert $WORD into the array
    WORDS[$INDEX]=$WORD
    # increment counter
    INDEX=$(($INDEX + 1))
done

echo "all words:   ${WORDS[*]}"

echo "first word:  ${WORDS[0]}"
echo "second word: ${WORDS[1]}"
echo "third word:  ${WORDS[2]}"
```

Comment: thanks. what if , if i have several word with space in second part. for example mytext 'one and two', how can i get the 'one and two'?